# How to save dynamic arrays of Objects in single array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I have some dynamic arrays of Objects (in C++) and using them in my implementation. How can I store these arrays in some single array. For example,

```
class classA{
} ;

class classB {

  private:
     // Dynamic arrays, initialized in constructor
     classA *arr1 ;
     classA *arr2 ;
     classA *arr3 ;
     classA *arr4 ;

  public:
     classB() {
         // initialization
         arr1  = new classA [10] ;
         arr2  = new classA [10] ;
         arr3  = new classA [10] ;
         arr4  = new classA [10] ;
     }

}
```

I want to save all these arrays in some other (static or dynamic) array

Comment: okay, I add the constructor of classB

Answer (score 2):

Just use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), it's known as dynamic array in C++ and is normally used as default container.

```
class classB
{
public:
    classB()
    : arr1(10), arr2(10), arrN(10)
    {}
private:
  std::vector<classA> arr1;
  std::vector<classA> arr2;
  //....
  std::vector<classA> arrN;
};
```

Update:

If you have a few vector and you want to add one to another. See below sample:

```
std::vector<classA> arr1;   
std::vector<classA> arr2;
// add something to arr1
// add something to arr2

arr1.insert(arr1.end(), arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
```

Comment: please explain how to add the dynamic arrays into a vector and how do I get these arrays "by using the index"

Comment: read up http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector, look at member functions like push_back, etc

Comment: No, I have to implement "STACK" by using the dynamic arrays. I have implemented but want to save all these arrays in one single array. I have to access all the dynamic arrays by using the indices, later

Comment: Just have one vector, then call std::vector::insert to add other vector to the end?